# Is it possible to reverse a confirmed transaction?

Tags: revert-transaction

I have been scammed by a so-called "trading account manager", he kept stalling until he told me my account had a problem and needed to be "rectified". Then, he told me I had to pay $300 for that, so I'm seek help to regain my funds.

Comment: A confirmed transaction cannot be undone.

Comment: Your funds are gone forever, report it to your local police and move on.

Answer (score 2):

No, a confirmed transaction can not be reversed.